# What is the practical difference between `_.defaults` and `_.extend`?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have been using `_.extends` as a way to get default options in my backbone views, like this:

```
options = _.extend({
    field: 'default-val'
}, options);
```

Now I recently discovered the `_.defaults` method which seemingly does the same, only with inverted arguments:

```
options = _.defaults(options, {
    field: 'default-val'
});
```

Apart from the switched arguments, I cannot find how these functions are different. So what is the practical difference between these two functions?

Comment: That's very easy to read from the source code: http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html (look for `undefinedOnly`)

Answer (score 4):

`.defaults` won't overrride an existing value where `.extend` will.

In your first example, `options` will be the reference to the new object created and overridden.

In your second example, `options` will only be changed if it doesn't have a `field` property.

Comment: So basically, extends creates a new object by combining the two given objects, and defaults just edits the object in the first argument? Does this mean I don't have to do `options = ` when using `_.defaults`?

Comment: no - `extend` and `defaults` both modify the first argument. in your case for `extend`, you would loose the reference to the extended options.

Answer (score 3):

if we look to [source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) we can see

```
_.extend = createAssigner(_.allKeys);
_.defaults = createAssigner(_.allKeys, true);
```

and

```
var createAssigner = function(keysFunc, undefinedOnly) {
    return function(obj) {
        var length = arguments.length;
        if (length < 2 || obj == null) return obj;
        for (var index = 1; index < length; index++) {
          var source = arguments[index],
          keys = keysFunc(source),
          l = keys.length;

          for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
              var key = keys[i];
              if (!undefinedOnly || obj[key] === void 0) obj[key] = source[key];
          }
      }
      return obj;
   };
};
```

so in `extend` always assign values from *source*, but in *defaults* only if *obj[key]* is *undefined*